# How can I check if a method is defined?

Tags: php, oop, methods, defined

I try to set the value of my variable to "", in the case that `getLove` is not defined:

```
`$money = $dollar->getCash()->getLove ?? "";`
```

But I get still the error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getLove" of class
>   "Proxies__CG__\App\Entity\Happiness".

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: But in the code you show it's not a method it's a property.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ah ok, that is why method exists not working

Comment: @AbraCadaver `$money = property_exists($dollar->getCash()->getLove(), 'getLove') ?? "";`

Comment: I get the error message: Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class`

Comment: So, is it a property `getLove` or a method `getLove()`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver Now I am confused. You said getLove() is not a method, it is a property

Comment: Symfony says it is a method

Comment: The way you were using it was a property without `()` but probably `$money = method_exists($dollar, 'getLove') ? $dollar->getCash()->getLove() : "";`

Comment: @AbraCadaver  Yeah, this is working actually!

Comment: @AbraCadaver Wait, not really working. Now I get the error `Call to a member function getLove() on null`

Comment: Is it possible to check also if it is null?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using [method_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php), note that this does not take "__call()" in consideration.

Comment: This is the correct answer: `$money = method_exists($dollar,"getCash") ? $dollar->getCash()->getLove() : '';` Do you want to update your answer like this?